# How can I set entity in HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, android, post, sharepoint, httpurlconnection

I'm sending a POST request to my share point server to create a list.I have the following JSON object.I want to set this as a body of my POST method using HttpURLConnection.

```
{ '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.List' }, 'AllowContentTypes': true, 'BaseTemplate': 100, 'ContentTypesEnabled': true, 'Description': 'My list description', 'Title': 'Test' }
```

can anyone guide me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is google down or something?

Comment: use this: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Y Is there any prob in answering my qn?